# ExtJS Ext.container.Container

Tags: extjs

I want add header ( with title ) to my class which extended by Ext.container.Container

```
Ext.define('MYPROJECRT.core.abstract.AbstractContainer', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
bodyPadding: 10,
padding: 10,
border: true,
margin: '0 0 0 5',
style: {
    borderColor: '#99BCE8',
    borderStyle: 'solid'
},

initComponent: function() {
  this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

Comment: was the answer below helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Container does not have a header. Use `Panel` component instead.